# npm i @truffle/hdwallet-provider - Error in truffle npm ERR! errno -4058

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a problem installing that truffle section to later export my contracts to the tesnet.

Somebody could help me?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm i @truffle/hdwallet-provider
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-08T23_22_56_392Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: It seems that you haven't installed Git, or—if you have—you haven't shown npm how to *find* the Git you installed. (This is an npm or general computer setup issue, and would happen regardless of which version-control-system you are using.)

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me:

```
npm i @truffle/hdwallet-provider@next
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.